# How to display Woocommerce products on my homepage?

Tags: woocommerce

I am beginner on wordpress and want to display all woocommerce products on my homepage..Please help!!!

I have try to customize the zerif-lite theme and add widgets section but cant get the result.

I also try to go Appreance->widget-> and start drag and drop but cant get the result.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have try to customize the zerif-lite theme and add widgets section
>   but cant get the result. I also try to go Appreance->widget-> and
>   start drag and drop but cant get the result.

¿Which widgets do you use? ¿Which exact result are you trying to get?

> display all woocommerce products on my homepage

if what you want is to **display all products in your homepage**... just use the Shop page (which displays all products) as Homepage.

```
Customize->HomePage Settings
```

HomePage Settings https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE7lh.jpg

ShopPage Settings https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UbC8.jpg